# How can I read remote sql tables into a winforms program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have an sql server table located on my website (remote). The table is called `table1` and contains a bunch of fields. My goal here is to read all the fields of `table1` into an array called `results`.

Here is my attempt:

```
 private static void ShowFields()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table1'", connection);

                string[] results = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery().ToArray();

                connection.Close(); 

                foreach (var v in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(v); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you succesfully connect to sql server? did you debugged it?

Comment: yeah the connection is fine. the problem is in extracting the fields from table1

Comment: A select query returns a `System.Data.Datatable` in ADO.NET. Look up `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method as well. You'll be able to retrieve the column values from its Datarows collection. If you edit your question to include your comment above, where you describe the actual problem you're having, I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Sqlcoomand.Executereader()` instead of:

```
 private static void ShowFields()
 {
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
     {
         connection.Open();

         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table1'", connection);
         SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

         connection.Close();

         int colCount = reader.FieldCount;

         while (reader.Read())
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(i));
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: this nearly works, but it shows all the properties of the table, rather than the the data in the fields---e.g., varchar, 50 dao, table etc

Comment: @John: I have updated my code, can you try it once. Just changed the last line to reader.GetString(i);

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to explore the

SqlCommand.ExecuteReader

or Fill a DataSet with the results.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

BeginExecuteNonQuery is async, I would pass on this one until you get the basics down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
 System.Data.DataTable T = new System.Data.DataTable();
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter DA = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(c);
 c.commandtext = "select ..";
 DA.SelectCommand = c;
 c.Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
 c.Connection.Open();
 DA.Fill(T);
        // close connection in finally block or use the using structure
```

Then examine T.